# which property of class "org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" should i use to timeout connection requests?

Tags: java, spring

I am new to Spring.
There is a service say x which sends a connection request.
I need to make a connection request timeout to amqpPublishConnectionFactory.

Which property should I set?

Code snippet of the context.xml file -

```
<beans:bean id="amqpPublishConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" destroy-method="stop" scope="singleton">
        <beans:property name="connectionFactory">
            <beans:bean class="org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnectionFactory">
                <beans:property name="remoteURI" value="failover:(amqps://#{appConfig.getBroker()}:#{appConfig.getConfig().getString('yam-settlement_amqp_port')})"/>

        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="maxConnections" value="30" />
```

Comment: you can  requestTimeout property for that it accepts `Long` values

Comment: @Jobin That is a property for org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration and not of org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory

Comment: yes. you can set it to the bean `connectionFactory` of type `org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnectionFactory`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jobin

Comment: @jobin does requestTimeout throw an exception? (its not throwing any for me)